# Snowsql command line

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Cannot seem to change the location install path of snowsql.

windows 10 from command line?

Documentation has this....

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#setting-the-download-directory-and-configuration-file-location.

```
$ SNOWSQL_DOWNLOAD_DIR=/var/shared snowsql -h
```

This is very confusing ^ from a windows 10 command line. doesn't work...
please help?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. What happens? Quote any error in full.

Answer (score 4):

The example provided on [the SnowSQL documentation page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#setting-the-download-directory-and-configuration-file-location) applies to macOS and Linux (given the path style used), but the general feature is usable through the concept of an *environment variable* which Windows' Command Prompt does support (and [can be set at more global levels](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html#zz-2.)).

```bsh
C:\> set SNOWSQL_DOWNLOAD_DIR=C:\CommonSharedDir\SnowSQL

C:\> snowsql
Installing version: 1.2.7  [####################################]  100%
[ … ]

C:\> dir C:\CommonSharedDir\SnowSQL
[ … ]

 Directory of C:\CommonSharedDir\SnowSQL

06/29/2020  09:44 PM    <DIR>          .
06/29/2020  09:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/29/2020  09:42 PM    <DIR>          1.2.7
06/29/2020  09:42 PM                42 autoupgrade

[ … ]
```